# HTACCESS Mod_Rewrite Troubles

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'm having a bit of trouble with my mod_rewrite, I had this running perfectly fine on my previous litespeed VPS. Now I'm using my own dedicated server running CentOS 6, so I don't know if I haven't configured correctly.

This is how it currently looks:

http://*********.com/?pageName=FourthPage

This is how I want it to look:

http://*********.com/FourthPage

This is my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?pageName=$1
```

Comment: Well what is the actual problem? Does the setup work as desired or not?

Comment: No it doesn't currently. It used to work, but since I've changed web server, it's no longer working.

Comment: Well and "it's no longer working" means what?

Comment: It's essentially doing nothing at all, the URL isn't being rewritten externally. So the URL stays looking like the first example.

Answer (score 1):

I am not good with htaccess syntax. Configuring such rules should be done directly in the server configuration if you have access. Using htaccess for such purposes is only a workaround. However:

The pattern inside the RequestRule is wrong. Especially the trailing slash ('/'). What is it meant to match? You might want to read again through the documentation of that rule. The pattern is not matched against a full URL but only against a part of the path in case of htaccess.

Have a try with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?pageName=$1
```

Also you should enable rewrite logging inside the server. The relevant configuration options are RewriteLog (for the file) and RewriteLogLevel (well, for the level...). It help to understand what is going on inside the rewrite module. However that cannot be done in htaccess too, you need access to the servers general configuration.

Comment: Nope, still not working :/ eugh this is annoying the hell out of me.

Comment: Again the same question: what does "not working" mean? Especially: what do the rewrite logs say?